# Typescript / node unable to resolve module paths

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I've completely new to both Express and Typescript.  I have *inherited* a project that is using express for an API.  I need to make some changes, but to get started, I can't even transpile the code.  I have been racking my brain trying to find a solution before turning to SO, but here I am, so please be kind.

When I run:

> npm run tsc

I get dozens of error messages that appear related to finding packages:

```
app/server.ts(2,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express'.
app/server.ts(11,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
app/server.ts(30,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
```

Here is my package.json

```js
{
"name": "my-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Express backend",
  "scripts": {
 "start": "node dist/server.js",
 "tsc": "tsc",
 "typings": "typings"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
 "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
 "cors": "^2.7.1",
 "express": "^4.14.0",
 "indicative": "^2.1.2",
 "jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.6",
 "lodash": "^4.16.1",
 "moment": "^2.17.1",
 "mongodb": "^2.2.1",
 "mongoose": "^4.5.4",
 "morgan": "^1.7.0",
 "node-uuid": "^1.4.8",
 "validator": "^5.5.0"
  },
  "repository": {},
  "devDependencies": {
 "tslint": "^3.11.0",
 "typescript": "^1.8.10",
 "typings": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Here's my tsconfig.js

```js
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "classic",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "outDir": "dist/"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I've installed all the packages running:

> npm install

The NPM log includes the following error:

```
9 verbose lifecycle my-backend@1.0.0~tsc: CWD: C:\Source\ExpressBackEnd
10 silly lifecycle my-backend@1.0.0~tsc: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'tsc' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-backend@1.0.0~tsc: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-backend@1.0.0~tsc: Failed to exec tsc script
13 verbose stack Error: my-backend@1.0.0 tsc: `tsc`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid my-backend@1.0.0
```

Any pointers / required reading is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it still happen if you just run `tsc` from the terminal?  I'm seeing some search results of npm not liking `npm run tsc` like you have set up above.

Comment: @Phix, yes, I still get the same errors running tsc from the terminal.

Comment: Hi mate, is this still an issue? just noticed this question from last year.

Answer (score -1):

My friend you need to install typescript definition files. Example: @types/node, @types/express ...

`npm install @types/node @types/express -D`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried running the command as suggested still getting the same errors, this is the output from the command: npm install @types/node @types/express -D
+ @types/express@4.11.1
+ @types/node@9.4.6
added 7 packages in 2.408s